# AngularJS, my first html component "widget"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I generated my first AngularJS app with yeoman
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

I created my first route and currently struggling with what to write on a directive and what on a controller, how to specify the JSON message in the APIService I receive from a POST or PUT (I have a backend ready)..

I created, with yeoman, a new service and tried to extend a code but I am getting the error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. The code in the service is:

```
angular.module('baApp').service('myService', function ($http, $q) {

this.getTiers = function(){
    $http.get('/data/tiers.json').success(function (data) {
        console.log('$http tiers');
        console.log(data);
    });
};
this.getCapabilities = function(){
    $http.get('/data/capabilities.json').success(function (data) {
        console.log('$http capabilities');
        console.log(data);
    });
};

return this;
});
```

and this the code in the controller:

```
angular.module('baApp')
    .controller('MyappCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {

    myService.getTiers().then(function(res){
    $scope.tiers = res;
        console.log('Tiers');
        console.log(res);
    });

    myService.getCapabilities().then(function(res){
        $scope.capabilities = res;
        console.log('Capabilities');
        console.log(capabilities);
    });

});
```

Comment: I edited my question, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

@Micky,

This may help you [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seow5k7f/1/)

I have added some sample code but if you need some dummy data from api till it is get ready then you can use json for mocking api response.

So this is sample code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope, myService){
myService.getData().then(function(res){
  $scope.data = res;
});
});
//service here
app.service('myService', function($http, $q){
var responseJson = {'message':'welcome to angular'}
this.getData = function(){
// call api or json file
// like
//return $http.get('api url or /test.json').

// fake response here
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.resolve(responseJson);
return deferred.promise;
}
return this;
});
```

Comment: Hi Jayant, thanks for the answer.. where should I link the html file (template)? I would like to use a Table or a Form as templates and reuse them one more times in the same single page html, treating them like widgets.. I am thinking and sure with your code and the yeoman support will figure out:-)

Comment: Thanks @Jayant, but my json is embedded..stored in a variable in an external file..what should I do instead of the $http.get?